# Method for proving continuity for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

We have that continuity  for a complex function is defined as such: *f is continuous at* $z=z_0$ *if it is defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and there exists a limit as*:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\longrightarrow z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)
\end{equation}

For the simple case, of $f(z)=\bar{z}$, it is not so obvious:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z}
\end{equation}

I define the neighbourhood as $(\bar{z}\pm\bar{z_0})$, and set the inequality $|\bar{z}\pm\bar{z_0}|\geq0$. I then calculate the limit for the neighborhood:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z}\pm\bar{z_0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z}\pm\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z_0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z}\pm\bar{z_0}=\bar{z_0}\pm \bar{z_0}=0, 2z_0
\end{equation}

Since 0 is not a complex number, while $2z_0$ is, we have that $\bar{z}$ can be said to be continuous $\mathbb{C}$ but not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}$.

This seems a little rudimentary, but is it valid as an approach to prove continuity for this function $f(z)=\bar{z}$?

Comment: Use the simple fact $|\overline z -\overline z_0|=|z-z_0|$.

Comment: $\lim_{\bar{z}\longrightarrow \bar{z}_0}\bar{z}$ is not the definition of continuity you wrote above. It should be $\lim_{z\longrightarrow z_0}\bar{z}$. In general, as a topological space, $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$ with the standard topology, so $f$ is continuous if and only if $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ (seen as functions of two variables via $z\to (x,y)$) are continuous.

Comment: OK, noted. I will not make an edit now, otherwise the whole question seems futile.

Comment: The statement "0 is not a complex number" is completely wrong. Also, saying that  "$\bar{}$ can be said to be continuous in ${\mathbb C}$  but not necessarily in ${\mathbb R}$" is not right either: The restriction of the complex conjugation to the real line is continuous, it equals the identity map.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{z\longrightarrow z_0}\bar{z}=\lim_{z\longrightarrow z_0}x-iy=\lim_{(x,y)\longrightarrow (x_0,y_0)}x-iy=x_0-iy_0$. Since $|x_0-iy_0|\geq0$. then f(z) is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Using the elementary definition for continuity $|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$ for $|z-z_0|<\delta$

so for $|z-z_0|=|\overline{(z-z_0)}|=|\bar z-\bar z_0|=|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\delta$ hence $\epsilon=\delta$. So $f(z)=\bar z$ is continuous.